# Given action "X", reducer "Y" returned undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a problem with Redux in React. After entering the title of this thread, I have been looking through some of the questions that were related but I couldn't find an answer to the same problem for my case.

I have The following files:

**Index.JS**

```
import snackbarContentReducer from '../src/shared/redux/reducers/snackbar-reducer';
import shoppingCartReducer from '../src/shared/redux/reducers/shopping-cart-reducer';
import userReducer from '../src/shared/redux/reducers/user-reducer';

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers(
        {
            //user: userReducer,
            //shopping_cart: shoppingCartReducer,
            snackbar_content: snackbarContentReducer
        }
    )
    ,window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension());


ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

User & Shopping cart are not implemented yet, actions and reducers for those don't have any code yet.

**App.JS**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setSnackbarContent } from '../src/shared/redux/actions/snackbar-actions';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            { console.log(this.props.snackbar_content) }
            { this.props.setSnackbarContent('nieuw') }

            //Cleared my routes here 

          </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    snackbar_content: state.snackbar_content
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return {
      setSnackbarContent : (text) => {
        dispatch(setSnackbarContent(text));
      }
  }
}
```

I can get the props from the store (as they are mapped from the state to the props). But I cannot change the snackbar_content in the store. The error that I get is the following:

> Error: Given action "SET_SNACKBAR_CONTENT", reducer "snackbar_content"
>   returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return
>   the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can
>   return null instead of undefined.

Which is caused by the following line:

```
dispatch(setSnackbarContent(text));
```

**snackbar-action.JS**

```
export const SET_SNACKBAR_CONTENT = 'SET_SNACKBAR_CONTENT';

export function setSnackbarContent(text){
    return { 
        type: SET_SNACKBAR_CONTENT, 
        payload: text
    }
}
```

**snackbar-reducer.JS**

```
import { SET_SNACKBAR_CONTENT } from '../actions/snackbar-actions';

export default function snackbarContentReducer(state = 'init snackbar', action){

    if(action.type === SET_SNACKBAR_CONTENT){
        return action.payload.snackbar_content;
    }

    return state;
}
```

Why does this error occur and how do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am fairly new to Redux, I have used the official docs and some YouTube video's for reference.

Comment: your reducer returns `snackbar_content` which will be undefined. The action uses `payload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be looking for `snackbar_content` in your action payload but you never set it, instead you set the payload to be whatever you expect the state to be.

In other words, in your reducer, just return `payload` as the state

```
if(action.type === SET_SNACKBAR_CONTENT){
    return action.payload;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You (and me) forgot to add the `default` case for `switch` statement in the reducer.

```
default:
   return state;
```